# Molecular concentration versus altitude

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

I am looking for a database that supplies molecular species as a function of altitude over a specific location.  For instance, I might want to look at methane concentration versus altitude over Wichita, KS. I've tried radiosonde data, but that does not include molecular species.

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://airnow.gov/index.cfm?action=airnow.local_city&cityid=472